# Displaying a concat array in an HTML element

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have multiple arrays that have been combined depending on user response. The only problem I have at this point is getting this final array to show up in the text field for the end user to see. Thanks for all the potential help!

```
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

//write password function 
function writePassword(){
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
  passwordText.value = password;
}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword)



//defining global var
var lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
var uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
var number = '1234567890'
var special = '!@#$%^&*()'
//generate password function gets called in writePassword function, and it should return the final password
function generatePassword(){

//blank array that will be the final password that is appended and shown to user
var chosenPassword = ''

//password length function
var passwordLength = prompt('How long would you like your password to be? (must be between 8 and 128 characters)')
if (passwordLength < 8 || passwordLength > 128) {
    alert('Must be between 8 and 128 characters!')
    return generatePassword();
}
//if boolean statements
var hasUpper = confirm('Would you like your passwords to have uppercase characters?')
  if (hasUpper === true) {
    chosenPassword = uppercase.concat(chosenPassword);
  }
var hasLower = confirm('Would you like your passwords to have lowercase characters?')
  if (hasLower === true) {
    chosenPassword = lowercase.concat(chosenPassword);
  }
var hasNumber = confirm('Would you like your passwords to have numbers?')
  if (hasNumber === true) {
    chosenPassword = number.concat(chosenPassword);
  }
var hasSpecial = confirm('Would you like your passwords to have special characters?')
  if (hasSpecial === true) {
    chosenPassword = special.concat(chosenPassword);
  }
//failsafe for no user info given
if (!passwordLength || !hasLower && !hasUpper && !hasNumber && !hasSpecial) {
  alert('Must provide some info to be contained in your password!')
}

//selecting rand function for chosenPass string
for (var i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
  password += chosenPassword.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chosenPassword)) 
}
return password;

}
```

I have narrowed the problem to either the write function or the generate function. The booleans and math.random functionality are working as expected and have confirmed this in the console.

EDIT: Adding HTML for those who have asked. As well as deleting the redundant function that was the same as the write password function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
      initial-scale=1.0" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
      <title>Password Generator</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
      <header>
         <h1>Password Generator</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-header">
            <h2>Generate a Password</h2>
         </div>
      <div class="card-body">
         <textarea
          readonly
          id="password"
          placeholder="Your Secure Password"
          aria-label="Generated Password"
         ></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
         <button id="generate" class="btn">Generate 
         Password</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Could you include your html? This way we can reproduce the problem in a working snippet ;)

Comment: Also you have a typo in 'genratepassword'

Comment: Ill add the HTML right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- `enterpassword` is a function that is never used (and has a spelling issue and missing parentheses). It looks to have the same purpose as `writePassword`, so it can be removed.
- `passwordLength` is going to be a string, better convert it immediately to a number data type, or else code will continue with some invalid input like "one"
- The expression for getting a random character is wrong. It should have `chosenPassword.length` instead of `chosenPassword`.
- The algorithm does not *ensure* that at least one character from each selected character group is taken. It only makes sure no other character is taken.

Some other remarks:

- Using `prompt` is not very user-friendly, as user is forced to follow that input path and cannot go back to change a previous answer. Use `input` elements instead (number and checkbox types), so that when user clicks the button, all input is already there.
- Avoid code repetition, and deal with each character group using the same code in a loop.

To ensure at least one character is taken from each selected character group, you could take a random character from each group, then append random characters from any group (like you did, or by shuffling & slicing), and then shuffle to get those first characters at random places too.

Here is your code adapted to work like that:

```js
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword)

function writePassword(){
    var password = generatePassword();
    var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
    passwordText.value = password;
}

function shuffle(arr) {
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

function randomFrom(arrayLike) {
    return arrayLike[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLike.length)];
}

// Avoid code repetition: deal with groups in an array and loops
var groups = [
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    '1234567890',
    '!@#$%^&*()',
];

function generatePassword() {
    var passwordLength = +document.querySelector("#length").value;
    if (Number.isNaN(passwordLength) || passwordLength < 8 || passwordLength > 128) {
        alert('Password length must be between 8 and 128 characters!')
        return;
    }
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]");
    var hasGroup = groups.map((group, i) => checkboxes[i].checked);
    if (!hasGroup.includes(true)) {
        alert('Must select some character groups to be contained in your password!')
    }

    // Collect all allowed characters
    var password = groups.filter((group, i) => hasGroup[i]).flatMap(s => [...s]);
    // Collect one character from each required group
    var needed = groups.map((group, i) => hasGroup[i] ? randomFrom(group) : "").filter(Boolean);
    shuffle(password);
    // Get the right number of characters, appending the required ones
    password.splice(passwordLength - needed.length, Infinity, ...needed);
    // Don't leave the needed characters at the end
    shuffle(password);
    return password.join("");
}
```

```html
Password length: <input id="length" type="number" value="8" min="8" max="128" style="width:3em"><br>
<input id="lowercase" type="checkbox" checked> Needs lowercase letter(s)<br>
<input id="uppercase" type="checkbox"> Needs uppercase letter(s)<br>
<input id="uppercase" type="checkbox"> Needs digit(s)<br>
<input id="uppercase" type="checkbox"> Needs special character(s)<br>
<button id="generate">Generate =></button>
<input id="password">
```

#### With prompt and confirm

Not ideal, but if you  really have to do this with `prompt` and `confirm`, then you can still reuse the logic of the above code, but change the input method:

```js
function getInputs() {
    while (true) {
        var passwordLength = prompt('How long would you like your password to be? (must be between 8 and 128 characters)');
        if (passwordLength >= 8 && passwordLength <= 128) break; // OK
        alert('Must be between 8 and 128 characters!');
    }
    while (true) {
        var hasGroup = ["uppercase", "lowercase", "numeric", "special"].map(group => {
            return confirm('Would you like your passwords to have ' + group + ' characters?')
        });
        if (hasGroup.includes(true)) break; // OK;
        alert('Must provide some info to be contained in your password!');
    }
    return [passwordLength, ...hasGroup];
}

var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword)

function writePassword(){
    var password = generatePassword();
    var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
    passwordText.value = password;
}

function shuffle(arr) {
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

function randomFrom(arrayLike) {
    return arrayLike[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLike.length)];
}

// Avoid code repetition: deal with groups in an array and loops
var groups = [
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    '1234567890',
    '!@#$%^&*()',
];

function generatePassword() {
    // Prompt user for inputs (yuk!)
    var [passwordLength, ...hasGroup] = getInputs();
    // Collect all allowed characters
    var password = groups.filter((group, i) => hasGroup[i]).flatMap(s => [...s]);
    // Collect one character from each required group
    var needed = groups.map((group, i) => hasGroup[i] ? randomFrom(group) : "").filter(Boolean);
    shuffle(password);
    // Get the right number of characters, appending the required ones
    password.splice(passwordLength - needed.length, Infinity, ...needed);
    // Don't leave the needed characters at the end
    shuffle(password);
    return password.join("");
}
```

```html
<button id="generate">Generate =></button>
<input id="password">
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help given in your response. I would be on board with using the more straight forward UI, but unfortunately this is part of a project where the prompt/ boolean method is mandatory.  Is there parts from your example that I can pull while meeting my requirements?

Comment: Yes, you can pull parts.

Comment: See addition to answer.